# Rundeck querying AWS WAF [Community edition]

Tags: rundeck, amazon-waf

I am new to creating jobs in Rundeck (community). I'd like to create a job under a project that accepts 2 parameters from the user (1. external/internal 2. IP CIDR) and then return if the IP CIDR already exists in WAF.

The current process is that user passes these parameters and the script has `aws-vault` command for the user to authenticate with the AWS account.

I have a shell script to do so but wondering how to do this using Rundeck jobs. Also, is there a way to allow the entire `Rundeck` instance (IAM roles?) to authenticate against a certain AWS account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a script on Rundeck:

1. Create a new Project, create a new job, give it a name, on the workflow tab select the "Script" step (you can pass the parameters on the "arguments" textbox) put the parameters on the ), put the script content there, and save and run the job.
2. Create a new Project, create a new job, give it a name, on the workflow tab select the "Script file or URL" step (you can pass the parameters on the "arguments" textbox), put the script file path there, and save and run the job.

> I have a shell script to do so but wondering how to do this using
> Rundeck jobs. Also, is there a way to allow the entire Rundeck
> instance (IAM roles?) to authenticate against a certain AWS account?

For [EC2](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin) remote instances, [S3](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/aws-s3-steps) actions, and some specific (and exclusive) Process Automation it's possible (the credentials are part of the plugin config).

For AWS WAF you can create a script using [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) tool with the rights parameters to execute it (or design your own AWS WAF [plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/01-plugin-development.html)).

Anyway, take a look at the [basic tutorial](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/tutorial/preparing.html) to learn how Rundeck works.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I might have missed asking in the original question. I use aws-vault to authenticate when I am running the script on Jenkins and local machine. Is there a way I could do that before actually running the IP check job?

Comment: Please update your question by adding these details. Try to explain your current process and what you want to reach with Rundeck.

Comment: Updated the question to explain the current process and what is required to reach from Rundeck.